# Pycharm not making MEDIA folder

Tags: python, django

Settings and urls.py file ..... Pycharm not able to create MEDIA folder :/ what is happening .. please guide ?

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media')


from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I ran server again n again but there is no error .. I am not getting what is the issue :(

Comment: You should create it manually and set appropriate permissions. Also `not able to create` is not clear and does not help to understand your actual problem.

Comment: Now I got it .. I made a new item in admin panel then it worked :)